# JsTree integration with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have product view. I want add to this view category tree. I think about jsTree.

I use in my project Laravel 7 and kalnoy/nestedset and https://www.jstree.com

Mi migration file:

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('category_name', 155);
            $table->string('description', 155)->nullable();
            $table->string('keywords', 155)->nullable();
            $table->longText('content')->nullable();
            $table->char('enable', 1)->default(0);
            $table->string('photo', 155)->nullable();
            $table->bigInteger('order')->default(0);
            $table->string('slug', 160)->nullable();
            NestedSet::columns($table);
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";
            $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
            $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
        });
```

In controller I have:

```
public function categoryTree(CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository, Request $request)
    {
        $nodes = $this->getCategoriesTree($categoryRepository->getTree());
        return $nodes;
    }

private function getCategoriesTree($nodes): array
    {
        $categoryArray = array();
        $traverse = function ($categories, $prefix = '-') use (&$traverse, &$categoryArray) {
            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                $categoryArray[] = ['id' => $category->id, 'name' => $prefix . ' ' . $category->category_name];
                $traverse($category->children, $prefix . '-');
            }
        };
        $traverse($nodes);
        return $categoryArray;
    }
```

And in repository:

```
public function getTree()
    {
        return $this->model->orderBy('order', 'ASC')->get()->toTree();
    }
```

My model is Category.

In result I have: https://pastebin.com/uErKGgHP

How can I convert my data to format jsTree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i don't know if you need a help to put the data in view or the format of data, but i will try to help explaining the format of json, the essencial elements must be 3: 
- Id: unique identificator of current element.
- Parent: id from parent, or use # when not have parent.
- Text: to show name of item.

Your current output data can't be accepted in jsTree format, you must adjust for this format:

```
  $('#yourdata').jstree({ 'core' : {
        'data' : [       
             {"id": 1,"parent":"#","text": "- Books"}, 
             {"id": 2,"parent":"1","text": "-- Comic Book"}
        ]
       } 
     });
```

It will show :

```
+ Book
-- Comic Book
```

as sub category

I hope it help.